Blazor WASM - Invalid HTTP header error in some versions of Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox
We are having an error that we aren't able to solve. We are developing a Blazor WASM application that connects to our web API. In our machines (Windows 10) it works fine, but when we tried to deploy it in a different machine (Windows 11) to test it, it fails in Chrome and Edge, while working in Firefox. Apparently the error is a format exception in an HTTP header. We use a custom header to pass a token (GUID). The name only has alphabetical characters, all of them ASCII. I am not sure this custom header is the cause. I changed request.Headers.Add to request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation, but the problem persists. Does anyone have any idea of what the problem could be?
Thank you!


Do you have any cors issues? Have you checked if the edge or chorme versions are different from the previous ones?

@Yuning Hi, thank you for replying. With the server allowing all (builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();), it fails nonetheless. I don't know how to check whether we are having a hidden CORS issue. With the same Edge version (127.0.2651.86) in my machine and the test machine, it works in the former and fails in the latter.

You can try to check if your computer is configured with the Intranet zone and then add localURL (the URL where  run the project) to the Local Intranet zone in Internet Options. Besides try a new test machine to check if the problem only occurs on one machine.
